# How to write a Generic ViewModel and ViewController class. I am trying to access a variable from the ViewModel without success?

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to create two generic classes.  A GenericViewModel and GenericUIViewController.  I am trying to access(from GenericUIViewController) a variable that is present in the GenericViewModel but without success.  I don't think I am quite sure on my feet with regards to the syntax and ways of writing these generic class.

GenericViewModel:

```
class ViewModel<T>{

public var items = [T]()

init() {
    items = getItems()

}

public func getItems() -> [T]{
    let items = [T]()
    return items
}
```

}

GenericUIViewController:

```
class MyGenericViewController<ViewModel>: UIViewController{

    var model: ViewModel!
    var collectionView: MyCustomCollectionView!

    func assignDependencies(modelObject: ViewModel){
    self.model = modelObject
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // At the parameter 'sourceData' Xcode does not recognise 'model.items' 
     collectionView = MyCustomCollectionView.init(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout, sourceData: model. , cellid: cellID, parentVC: self, spacingBetweenCells: spacing, numCellsPerRow: 3)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think correct code will be. Hope it helps

```
class MyGenericViewController: UIViewController{

var model: ViewModel<String>!
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

func assignDependencies(modelObject: ViewModel<String>){
    self.model = modelObject
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you need that ViewController has generic ViewModelItemType then:

```swift
class MyGenericViewController<ViewModelItemType>: UIViewController {
    var model: ViewModel<ViewModelItemType>!

    func assignDependencies(modelObject: ViewModel<ViewModelItemType>) {
        self.model = modelObject
    }
}
```

Not sure why, but maybe. :)  I think Alexandr Kolesnik's comment will be enough!